# Перевернуть вектор

Tags: c++, вектор

Как быстро перевернуть вектор?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Имеется по крайней мере два подхода.

Первый - это использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::reverse`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`

Второй - это просто присвоить вектор самого себе, используя реверсивные итераторы.

А если просто надо вывести вектор в обратном порядке на консоль, то вы также можете использовать обычный цикл с реверсивными итераторами, либо с индексами, либо алгоритм `std::reverse_copy`

Вот демонстрационная программа, показывающая все перечисленные методы за исключением метода assign, который мог бы выглядеть следующим образом

```
v.assign( v.rbegin(), v.rend() );
```

К сожалению большинство реализаций стандартных библиотек содержат баг, и вышеуказанное предложение выполняется неверно.:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse( v.begin(), v.end() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it ) std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = v.size(); i != 0; )
    {
        std::cout << v[--i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse_copy( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                       std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;                       

}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

В этой программе вызов `std::reverse` реверсирует сам вектор, а все остальные части программы просто выводят на консоль уже реверсированный вектор в обратном порядке

Comment: что еще за баг???

Comment: и что за странный цикл `for ( int x : v )`? где 3 выражения??

Comment: @supermen_666 Неправильно присваивают вектор самому себе.

Comment: @supermen_666 Это введенный в стандарт языка C++ в 2011 так называемый for-цикл на основе диапазонов.

Comment: В Dev C++ 5.4.2 работает???

Comment: @supermen_666 должно обязательно работать, если задан параметр компилятора поддержки C++2011. Вы можете это проверить самостоятельно, запустив программу на выполнение.

Comment: респект брат)))

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `std::reverse`:

```
std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: За логарифмическое время???

Comment: это медленно надо чеб быстро

Comment: мну сказали чем бырее тем выше оценку поставят